# Tracking each request logs in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having a web application that was build on node and express in its backend. My web site having lot of users so my logs that really confusing when I try to debug with help of logs(console.log) in case of any issues. Logs get clumsy among different users, Is there any way to track the logs with respect to request (Request ID kinda thing)?

Answer (score 0):

recommend you simple log middleware, for example https://github.com/villadora/express-bunyan-logger

```
app.use(require('express-bunyan-logger').errorLogger());
app.use(require('express-bunyan-logger')({
    name: 'logger',
    streams: [{
        level: 'info',
        stream: process.stdout
        }]
    }));

app.use(require('express-bunyan-logger')({
    format: ":remote-address - :user-agent[major] custom logger"
});

app.use(require('express-bunyan-logger')();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.log.debug('this is debug in middleware');
    next();
});
```

You can castumize logger, write difference data to file ot stdout.